# Catching exception: error: svd() failed to converge

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I've written a function that uses Armadillo `svd_econ` function. I'm trying to handle the case where the `svd` fails to converge, because for some reason it doesn't abort the function in that case.

The error in question reads:

```
error: svd_econ(): failed to converge
```

Based on my reading of the [SVD documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svd), this should throw a `std::runtime_error`, and based on my reading of the [Exceptions tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/), I should be able to handle it like so:

```
arma::mat U, V;
arma::vec S;
try {
  // aDat and subsetRows are previously defined
  arma::svd_econ(U, S, V, aDat.rows(subsetRows), "right", "dc");
} catch (std::runtime_error e) {
  std::cout << "Exception caught!" << std::endl;
  // I want to abort, and return the error to R:
  throw Rcpp::exception(e.what());
}
```

However, when I run this code with a case that gives me the error message above, I get a segfault. If I remove the try-catch block, the code keeps going, and throws an error further down when the code tries to use the results of the SVD.

I assume I'm just missing something obvious since I haven't formally learnt any `C++`

Comment: You read the documentation wrong for [svd_econ()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#svd_econ). It states: _if the decomposition fails, the output objects are reset and a bool set to false is returned_.  So, something along these lines should work: `bool success = svd_econ(...)`, and then check whether `success` is `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, I'd just try a few things:

- a reference to the exception,
- just error forwarding to R, not another `throw()`,
- a default block with `Rf_error()`

So maybe (untested)

```
try {
  arma::svd_econ(U, S, V, aDat.rows(subsetRows), "right", "dc");
} catch (std::runtime_error & e) {
  std::cout << "Exception caught!" << std::endl;
  forward_exception_to_r(e);
} default(...) {
  Rf_error("Unknown exception");
}
```

but in essence you get all this for free via Rcpp Attributes as this is what the (automatically inserted) `END_RCPP` macro does --- see Section 2.7 of the Rcpp book for more details.

*Edit* But @mtall, in his comment, does what we should have done first: check the Armadillo docs. So you can simply check the return value.  But you may want to try the suggested try/catch as well.